# WITH... UPDATE in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, common-table-expression

I'm trying to update a table (in pgsql) with a complex expression that needs to occur several times in the UPDATE statement.  WITH seems perfect for this:

```
WITH newtz AS (SELECT timezone FROM timezonebyzipcode WHERE zip=(SELECT zip_code FROM company WHERE id=company_id))
UPDATE cross_rental
SET return_timezone=newtz
return_time=(return_time AT TIME ZONE return_timezone) AT TIME ZONE newtz
WHERE return_to='Vendor' AND return_timezone<>newtz
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
LINE 2: UPDATE cross_rental
        ^
```

I've searched and couldn't find any examples of using WITH with UPDATE in this way, but I also don't see anything indicating it shouldn't work.  Is this just unsupported, or am I making some silly mistake?

And, if it's unsupported, should I just copy that nasty long expression into each of the three places where I'm using "newtz" in the UPDATE clause?  Or is there some better way to accomplish this update?

Comment: I've come to realize that the WITH clause creates a temporary view, not a scalar variable.  But even changing the query to make and use it as a view, it still chokes when it gets to UPDATE.  It looks as though you just can't use WITH with UPDATE (though the docs seem to claim otherwise).

Comment: `newtz` is not a field name but the name for the CTE (syntactically comparable to a table alias)

Comment: @JoeStrout It's more accurate to say that in PostgreSQL it creates a temporary *materialized* view. CTE terms always get materialized. (BTW, **always show your PostgreSQL version in questions**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
>    LINE 2: UPDATE cross_rental

This specific error message reveals you're using a PostgreSQL version 9.0 or older. The two major versions before 9.1 featured CTEs and `WITH`, but not in the context of data modifying queries.
This appeared in 9.1. See [7.8.2. Data-Modifying Statements in WITH](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) in PostgreSQL 9.1 doc.

Assuming a newer version, a CTE must be used as a table with rows and columns (not as a scalar variable), so the query should be fixed as mentioned in [Richard Huxton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729550/238814).

Comment: Aha, I think that's it.  I am indeed using version 9.0.  I can't easily test it in 9.1, but I have no reason to suspect you're not absolutely right, so I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH (SELECT timezone FROM timezonebyzipcode WHERE zip=(SELECT zip_code FROM company WHERE id=company_id)) AS newtz
```

You have the alias and referent backwards...

Comment: That doesn't match the docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html), which clearly put the alias first.  But I tried it anyway, and it produces a syntax error at the first '('.

Answer (score 0):

It's a table (or a from-recordset-source anyway).

```
WITH calculated AS (
    SELECT ....
)
UPDATE foo
SET bar = calculated.something
FROM calculated
WHERE ...
```